# ShortcutBadger library implementation

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push

I want to implement ShortcutBadge, to show counter for push notification on my app icon.
gotten from: https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger

i have added the library successfully.
my app has GcmMessageListenerService.java class.

and below methods.

onMessageReceived()

showNotification()

i am suppose to use like this:

```
    int badgeCount = 1;
    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(context, badgeCount);
```

but cant get it to work when i paste above code on any of my methods on GcmMessageListenerService.java.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does your launcher support badging feature?

Comment: No. am implementing in android